# Media images not displaying from AWS S3 in django app

Tags: python, django, image, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

It seems that I've configured all right, and in the dev tools or terminal no errors. Even the file crash icon disappeared.

settings.py (i removed the name and other data that shouldn't be public

```
STATIC_URL = "staticfiles/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

# amazon s3
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % os.environ.get('')
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = ''
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = ''
AWS_S3_VERIFY = True

# config/settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/images/')
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
```

models.py

[image]
index.html

```
{% for auction in allAuctions %}
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <img src="{{ auction.image.url }}" class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%"
                 height="225"
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"
                 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" style="object-fit: cover;">
{% endfor %}
```

my s3 policy
[image]

also the s3 bucket
[image]
and how it looks like
[image]

Comment: Can you open the image in a browser from the URL?  Also check the URL against your `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN`.  Depending on the region, AWS sometimes constructs the URL differently (dash vs dot)

Comment: All works great, but the error is in the {{auction.image.url}}, in my dev inspector, image "src" is empty. I hard coded and made the src="link_of_the_image_path + {{auction.image}}". And all works, but I think it is not good practice. For the PET project is enough.